# Auto Custom Row Numbering in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

In the attached image [excel sheet] I have added custom column [SL NO] where I want to keep custom row number. In the middle of the row I have also added custom heading [A,B,C,D], When I add custom heading [A,B,C,D] the custom row number [ SL NO] is not increasing automatically, Generally I should not work as it is custom row number. But my requirement is to keep auto adjusting or row numbering even if I delete any row or add more heading in the middle of the row like [ [E,F,G...].  How can I do that?

[image: Custom SL NO is not increasing automatically after using a row as heading (A,B,C...) in the middle of the row]

Comment: I want the same thing but with correct custom row number. Look, after row number 7 [Azerbaijan] I add new heading B with green background, look again current row number 9 [Bahamas] but it should be row number 8 automatically when I add the heading B. Got it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula in A3 and copied down to suit:

```
=IF(LEN(B3)=1,"",MAX(A$1:A2)+1)
```

will integer increment (starting at one more than the largest number above A3 - in this case there isn't one, so `0`) while skipping rows in which the text in ColumnB is a single character.

Comment: Simply Cool. (Y) 
Thanks a lot. 

One question, LEN is returning the total number of character and based on that you skipping. But my heading may vary. I want dynamic something. And could you please explain the second part  MAX(A$2:A2)+1) as I have zero knowledge in excel.

Comment: In that case you can differentiate the data by using filter by color option and select green background and enter single digit value in nearby the column and redirect the reference of the the given formula to that cell.